# Firebase hosting + custom server are incompatible?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, socket.io, firebase-hosting

My expressjs+Socket.io server runs on a Raspberry Pi. When trying to connect to the express, there is a http+https incompatibility that Firebase doesn't seem to like. Tells me to use Https instead. When using Https, I get Certificate errors. So I went and bought myself a brand new SSL certificate from my domain provider and... on my local machine, where I accidentally installed the certificate, everything works fine, but on my laptop or mobile, when I go to the website, it says "(net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID)". I am not sure what to do, since many resources online cover only how to bypass this problem on their machine, without fixing the problem for everyone.

Server.js

```
var app = require("express")();
var https = require("https");
var fs = require("fs");

var server = https.createServer(
  {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./sslkey.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./sslcert.crt'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('./sslca.ca-bundle'),
  },
  app
);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
  console.log("User connected");
})
server.listen(4444, function() {
  console.log("listening on *:4444");
});
```

I also use Socket.io with Angular and I couldn't find a way to disable "rejectUnauthorized", as many suggested to skip the SSL check.

Any help?

Comment: I don't understand how Firebase Hosting is involved here.  Seems like you already have your own web server and have no need for Firebase Hosting.

Comment: @DougStevenson I use firebase to have a domain name connected. Right now I'm trying to set a web server, but with no luck so far.

Comment: You can't really have Firebase Hosting along with another web server.  Firebase Hosting *IS* effectively your web server for static content. You can't have a nodejs server running alongside that, but you can delegate some urls to Cloud Functions.

Comment: @DougStevenson My webserver is more like just a server, it doesn't serve any html or javascript files. It is used for socket.io websockets and safer database communication. However now I have switched from firebase hosting to a webserver like you thought I was doing but I still get the same SSL errors, net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID